# how to control the bandwidth in LAN with no server?

Tags: router, switch, adsl

i have an ADSL line with a router attached to it. the router is attached with a switch. and with this switch, i have 3 PC connected each sharing the internet connection.

i there any way to distribute internet bandwidth among each PC. (it shouldn't be a QoS solution because my router don't support this) ?

thanks.

Comment: Either get a server or get a router with QoS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so let me  get that right: You have an infrastructure that can not control bandwidth and you want to do wit without changing the infrastructure?

Gratulations. Please fry me a totally vegetarian real argentinian meat steak. Get the idea? Just because someone wants something does not mean it can happen.

Solution: GET THE PROPER INFRASTRUCTURE. A router upgrade most likely is cheapest (OpenWRT can be installed on quite some end user routers), or you simply get a proper router. I am in a relatively similar position, and I am thus getting a proper router to fullfill my needs.

Comment: I agree entirely.  You want good features? Don't be a cheapskate.

Comment: I'd go one step further, and say don't be cheap on the new router.  Get a decent cisco.

Comment: No need for that. Well, higher end I prefer Extreme Networks, but ther are some NICE Linux based distros, and there is ONE atom based small box out with 8 gigabit lan ports that one can buy.

Comment: I have done bandwidth control by upgrading router and installing Openwrt.

Comment: Nice. Great - see ;) Upgrading the infrastructure worked. Plus OpenWRT is no a bad router.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC operating systems support it, you could set up ingress policing and egress traffic shaping on each PC, so that each cooperatively limits itself to 1/3 of the maximum download and upload rates of your ADSL, respectively.

For example, in Linux, the following from [this blog](http://blog.stevedoria.net/20050906/ingress-policing-with-linux-and-tc) uses ingress policing to limit incoming traffic to 256 kbps:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol ip prio 50 \
   u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 police rate 256kbit \
   burst 10k drop flowid :1
```

The following [from the same blog](http://blog.stevedoria.net/20050906/ingress-policing-with-linux-and-tc) uses the "Token Bucket Filter" (tbf) queuing discipline to limit outgoing traffic to 256 kbps:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf \
   rate 256kbit latency 25ms burst 10k
```

There is a lot more information about traffic policing, shaping, and routing in the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control Howto](http://lartc.org/howto/).

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if only one of the PCs is using the internet, and in a QoS scenario could use the full link, it can't use more than what you set it to.

Comment: @mfinni: Yes, I agree that is a problem, but I don't know of any non-QoS solutions to fully utilize the link. Is such even possible?

Comment: No, there isn't. Which is why QoS is the best solution, even if Azfar ruled it out in his question.

Comment: @mfinni: Fair enough. Post your solution and I will happily upvote it.

Comment: TomTom already gave the best answer. I'm not saying your solution wouldn't work, it just wouldn't be optimal.

Comment: @mfinni: Uh, if QoS is the best answer, then TomTom's "answer" is certainly NOT it. But I'm really at a loss to understand what you've been driving at here. Yes, my answer is non-optimal. So what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kit you're using, but it MAY be that it has something similar to Cisco's "fair scheduling" (that is, trying to alternate packets from different streams, so that, as far as possible, all users are services similarly).

If you check the manual for your router, it MAY mention thishow to set this (if it is, at all, possible).

Answer (score 0):

This program can do it:

http://bandwidthcontroller.com/tutorialDistributedMode.html

but I think it's for Win XP.

The program is called "Bandwidth Controller."

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.